# Installed NodeJS v6.2.2 but Check NodeJS Version Shows v0.10.13 on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, version

Currently, I installed the latest version of node (v6.2.2) on Windows 10 and when I use the command `node -v` or `node --version` to check the version of the node, it shows me that the version is `v0.10.13`. It is normal? If it is not normal, how can I fix it? since I already tried to reinstall node it several times.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found out the answer. If this answer seems not good enough, please feel free to edit it and add more detail. Thank you.

Use **Command Prompt** to do the checking.

```
C:\Users\User>node -v
v6.2.2
```

With **Windows PowerShell**, I can just see:

```
C:\Users\User>node -v
v0.10.13
```